# Was ist eine "Hochwertfähigkeit"?

Tags: meaning, legal-terminology

Was bedeutet »Hochwertfähigkeit«?

Dieser Begriff scheint ausschließlich in einem militärischen Kontext verwendet zu werden. Beispiele:

- [Unterrichtung durch die Bundesregierung - Drucksache 18/5132 (PDF)](http://dipbt.bundestag.de/dip21/btd/18/051/1805132.pdf):

  > Vor allem mit der Ressource strategischer luftgestützter Verwundetentransport stellte Deutschland eine **Hochwertfähigkeit** für EUFOR RCA.
- [BMVg: Staatssekretär referiert zur Beziehung zwischen USA und Europa](https://www.bmvg.de/portal/a/bmvg/!ut/p/c4/NYvBCsIwEET_aDcRAtabpSDepBdbb2kbwkqTlHXTXvx4k4Mz8A7zGHxhabQ7eSuUol1xwHGmy3TAFHYP75S5rBAo0kccUw74rJ_FwZyik0pxUajQs5XEsCWWtZrMXAzQgqPSXau0-kd_G_O4meZsTt297XEL4foDwY9CDA!!/)

  > Die USA hingegen unterstützen die Europäer und die einheimischen Truppen mit Aufklärungsmitteln und anderen **Hochwertfähigkeiten**, ohne selbst mit größeren Truppenkontingenten vor Ort zu sein.
- [Bundesregierung: "Kampf gegen Terror geht alle an"](https://www.bundesregierung.de/Content/DE/Interview/2015/11/2015-11-27-von-der-leyen-hbl.html):

  > Deutschland hat ein starkes Paket geschnürt, um Frankreich zur Seite zu stehen. Die Angebote umfassen **Hochwertfähigkeiten** in der Aufklärung, aber auch Luftbetankung und Schutz für den französischen Flugzeugträger vor der syrischen Küste.
- [Weissbuch zur Sicherheitspolitik und zur Zukunft der Bundeswehr (PDF)](https://www.bmvg.de/resource/resource/MzEzNTM4MmUzMzMyMmUzMTM1MzMyZTM2MzIzMDMwMzAzMDMwMzAzMDY5NzE3MzM0Nzc2YzYyMzcyMDIwMjAyMDIw/Weissbuch2016_barrierefrei.pdf):

  > Die Bundeswehr muss sich als Hochwertziel für staatliche wie nichtstaatliche Akteure und als Instrument der wirksamen Cyberverteidigung für den Umgang mit komplexen Angriffen aufstellen. Die Verteidigung gegen derartige Angriffe bedarf auch entsprechender defensiver und offensiver **Hochwertfähigkeiten**, die es kontinuierlich zu beüben und weiterzuentwickeln gilt.

Im letzten Zitat ist auch von »Hochwertziel« die Rede. Damit scheint [*hochrangiges Ziel* (high-value target)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-value_target) gemeint zu sein, oder? Ist *Hochwertfähigkeit* dann auch eine (etwas ungewöhnliche) Übersetzung eines englischen Begriffs?

Als ich *Hochwertfähigkeit* zum ersten Mal gehört habe, dachte ich spontan an eine *hochwertige* Fähigkeit. Ist das also nur eine Alternative dazu? Oder hat es im militärischen Kontext eine spezielle(re) Bedeutung?

»Hochwert« hat [laut Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hochwert) nur eine Bedeutung in der Kartographie:

> in einem Koordinatensystem der Abstand zu einer festgelegten Basislinie

Comment: Klingt, als sei es eine wenig inspirierte Übersetzung einer englischen (US, NATO) Phrase die mit *high value* beginnt.

Comment: *beüben* ist auch eine schöne Wortschöpfung in deinem Zitat, die der Duden nicht kennt.

Comment: Ich betrachte *Hochwertfähigkeit* auch als unnötig wörtliche Übersetzung eines US-amerikanischen Militärfachbegriffes. Möglicherweise macht man das, damit die NATO-Partner in den Verlautbarungen ihre vereinbarten Schlüsselworte einfach wiederfinden...

Answer (score 4):

Hochwertfähigkeit ist nicht im Duden gelistet, daher kannst du grundsätzlich bereits davon ausgehen, dass die Verbreitung irrelevant oder derart geringfügig ist, dass es nicht zum effektiven deutschen Sprachkorpus zählt.

In den Beispielen und zahlreichen anderen, die man im Netz findet, ist eine *Hochwertfähigkeit* so viel wie eine wichtige, nützliche und stark ausprägte Fähigkeit. Quasi eine *hochwertige Fähigkeit*. Es handelt sich hierbei – meines Erachtens – um einen stilistischen Neologismus. Dieser scheint durch einige wenige Nennungen durch die Bundeswehr innerhalb der Militärsprache verhäuft vorzukommen, ist aber dennoch als Stilmittel zu betrachten.

Comment: Bin mit deiner Antwort einig, ausser den beiden Punkten *Neologismus* und *Stilmittel* - Ich denke, es handelt sich eher um die *Abwesenheit eines Stilmittels*, also eine möglichst wortgetreue Übersetzung (das ist für mich kein Neologismus) der wahrscheinlich im Original auf Englisch abgefassten gemeinsamen Direktive, um sich nicht dem Vorwurf einer "Reinterpretation bei der Übersetzung" auszusetzen.

Comment: Definitiv möglich, allerdings beobachte ich auch den Trend von Staatsorganen und ähnlichen Institutionen ungewöhnlich viele Kofferwörter zu bilden. Deshalb habe ich es als Stilmittel betrachtet

Comment: Ist eine direkte Übernahme eines Begriffs aus dem Englischen nicht ein „Anglizismus”?

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass man »im Duden verzeichnet« mit »gehört zum effektiven deutschen Sprachkorpus« gleichsetzen kann. Ersteres ist weder hinreichend noch notwendig für zweiteres.

Comment: Wenn man weiß, wie der Duden kompiliert wird, ist es durchaus begründet das gleichzusetzen. Bei neuartigen Trendwörtern ist der Duden nicht immer topaktuell, aber bei solchen Begriffen, wäre er es! Zumindest die Online-Fassung.